# Highcharts vs highcharts2. Which one is the recomended one to use?

Tags: highcharts

There are two versions on npm for highcharts. Which one is the recomended one to use.

Versions.

```
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
node: 6.11.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/animations: 4.1.3
@angular/common: 4.1.3
@angular/compiler: 4.1.3
@angular/core: 4.1.3
@angular/forms: 4.1.3
@angular/http: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
@angular/router: 4.1.3
@angular/cli: 1.4.7
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3
typescript: 2.3.3
```

Comment: **"highcharts"** is an official npm package: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-npm

I couldn't find any npm package called 'highcharts2'.

Comment: Hi Kamil, there is actually a couple: highcharts, angular2-highcharts,  ng2-highcharts. I could not get any of the 3 working on angular 4

Comment: Here's Angular 4 demo that uses **npm-highcharts**: http://plnkr.co/edit/wrXwWLtCM5LymRgjDb2o?p=preview